How are users bypassing Meta Verified restrictions by changing the payment country to Japan?
I’ve heard about a method where users bypass Meta Verified restrictions by changing their payment country to Japan. I want to understand the technical process behind this. Specifically:
1.  How does changing the payment country affect eligibility for Meta Verified?
2.  What kind of code, tools, or scripts might users employ to make such changes?
3.  Are there specific steps or API interactions they rely on to achieve this bypass?

Note: This question is for educational purposes to understand the technical aspects and potential vulnerabilities, not to endorse or perform such actions.

Researching how changing the payment country to Japan allows Meta Verified bypass but couldn’t find clear steps or technical details.
